# Created Docker image but docker run throws Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain

Tags: docker, gradle, gatling, scala-gatling

I have created Docker image based on your project but docker run throws Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.Here is dockerfile if you want to debug and run and help me in fixing this error

```
FROM OpenJDK:8-JDK-alpine

WORKDIR /opt

RUN wget -q https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-bin.zip 
&& unzip gradle-3.3-bin.zip -d /opt 
&& rm gradle-3.3-bin.zip

RUN echo "$PWD"

RUN apk add git

RUN git clone https://github.com/TechieTester/gatling-fundamentals.git

RUN echo "$PWD"

RUN cp -vif /opt/gatling-fundamentals/gradlew /opt/gradle-3.3/bin/

RUN mv -vif /opt/gatling-fundamentals/src/* /opt/gradle-3.3/bin/

RUN find /opt/

RUN chmod 777 /opt/gradle-3.3/bin/gradlew

ENV GRADLE_HOME /opt/gradle-3.3
ENV PATH $PATH:/opt/gradle-3.3/bin
```

Once docker image created successfully using below command locally

```
docker build -t fromscratch4:local .
```

try to run with below command
Mind you i have given full access to gradlew using

```
chmod 777 gradlew
```

You will get an error saying below...please help

```
PS C:\Gatling2\gatling6games> docker run --rm -w /opt/gatling-fundamentals/ 
fromscratch4:local sh -c "gradle wrapper | gradlew gatlingRun 
simulations.RuntimeParameters"
Error: Could not find or load main class 
org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
```

Comment: Hi Margaret, welcome to SO!. Why are you executing `cp -vif /opt/gatling-fundamentals/gradlew /opt/gradle-3.3/bin/`? The whole purpose of `gradlew` **in that project** is such that it will download [the gradle 4.5.1 it wants to use](https://github.com/TechieTester/gatling-fundamentals/blob/master/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties#L6). I also don't understand why you are running `gradle wrapper` and piping its output into `gradlew`; that is very, very, very bizarre

Comment: Sorry i am very new to docker hence trying everything which works,actually all i need is to execute below  command ./gradlew gatlingRun simulations.RuntimeParameters this is a execution of tool called gatling performance ...the github repository which i am using is https://github.com/TechieTester/gatling-fundamentals.git..above github repository workinf perfectly in my local windows,now i want to dockerise,please help

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel this is command  ./gradlew gatlingRun simulations.RuntimeParameters which i want to execute with docker run,i tried mapping above cmd with docker run --rm  -w /opt/gatling-fundamentals/ fromscratch4:local grad
lew gatlingRun simulations.RuntimeParameters but same error

Comment: You will have a much nicer time here, and improve the lives of folks who read your questions and comments, if you take a minute to learn how to [use the formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting), which is especially true for `code snippets` to make them more legible

Comment: What I am saying is that you only want to run the `git clone https://...` part, then ensure you run `./gradlew gatlingRun simulations.RuntimeParameters` (with the leading dot-forwardslash: `./` but installing a separate gradle is only making your situation worse, **especially** since the version you are installing is very old

Comment: $'Cloning into 'gatling-fundamentals'...
    Removing intermediate container 368bf9064f27
    ---> 733ef05c7201
    Removing intermediate container 00a7de59d819
    ---> b9ed3bcdbe11
    Step 8/10 : RUN ./gradlew gatlingRun simulations.RuntimeParameters
    ---> Running in ff254d14a18b
    /bin/sh: ./gradlew: not found
    The command '/bin/sh -c ./gradlew gatlingRun simulations.RuntimeParameters' returned a non-zero code: 127'

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel docker says Step 8/10 : RUN ./gradlew gatlingRun simulations.RuntimeParameters
 ---> Running in ff254d14a18b
/bin/sh: ./gradlew: not found

Answer (score 0):

Response of @MatthewLDaniel worked

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel could you please provide resolution for [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53753665/10752305)